# Why are these 3 lines used?

Tags: hash

```
for(int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++){
    if(mp.find(A[i]) == mp.end()){
        if(mp.find(B-A[i]) == mp.end())
        mp[B-A[i]] = i;
    }
```

Why are these three lines of code used here? explain in detail please

[complete solution link](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/2-sum/)

Comment: Please add more context to your question, including a proper problem statement.

Comment: There are 5 lines so which 3 are referring to?  You are also missing a } at the end.  What type and value are mp, A & B?  What language is this?  It appears the loop iterates through an array A.  Then updates mp[B-A[i]] = i if both mp.find(A[i]) and mp.find(B-A[i]) are equal to mp.end.  I am guessing that mp.find and mp.end return indexes, so it checks if A[i] and B-A[i] are both the last element of mp.  I don't know what the behavior is if B < A[i].